# Cant access github from a remote server. Autentication errors?

Tags: git, github

So I have been struggling to deploy an app that I build recently because I cannot seem to git clone on a remote server. I added in the github cli got access to my github. Like so:

```
gh auth login
? What account do you want to log into? GitHub.com
? What is your preferred protocol for Git operations? SSH
? Upload your SSH public key to your GitHub account? /home/indy/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
? How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI? Login with a web browser

! First copy your one-time code: ****-****
- Press Enter to open github.com in your browser...
! Failed opening a web browser at https://github.com/login/device
  exec: "xdg-open,x-www-browser,www-browser,wslview": executable file not found in $PATH
  Please try entering the URL in your browser manually
✓ Authentication complete. Press Enter to continue...

- gh config set -h github.com git_protocol ssh
✓ Configured git protocol
✓ Uploaded the SSH key to your GitHub account: /home/.../.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
✓ Logged in as ********
```

Now I know I have logged in but I cannot seem to clone any repos. I can plainly see that my github profile has a new key and everything and yet here is the error that I am getting:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit status 128
```

Comment: Hi *****! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 1988, received 2388 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 35017.3, received 42063.0
debug1: Exit status 1

But cant git clone

Comment: Yes the correct username is displayed.
Also ls-remote gives me all the heads in the code. But I still cant seem to clone it to my server

Comment: Well I cant seem to clone a repo to begin with so Im not sure how remote -v would work?

Comment: If `git ls-remote` works when given the URL, `git clone` *should* work when given the *same* URL, because both are using that URL to gain (read) access to the repository. If they're not, it's time for some really low level debugging, such as inspecting packet traces.

Comment: Okay, totally different issue, I have figured it out. Answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So this isnt a Github issue but rather how the whole thing was set up. The user account that I was logging in from was a sudo user and not the root user. All of these accounts need a

```
sudo mkdir ..
```

etc etc in front of them.
But since I typed in sudo, git was looking in the root folder for a ssh key to check against my account to log me in and didn't find anything. So things like gh auth etc worked. But the moment I wanted to clone something I had to make a new folder and needed sudo privileges.

So this was a security issue and not really anything else.